# Substring equality problem using hash function

Tags: python, c++, hash

I am a beginner to hash function. I tried to implement the substring equality problem using hashes.

**Problem Description**

**Input Format**. The first line contains a string  consisting of small Latin letters. The second line contains
the number of queries . Each of the next  lines specifies a query by three integers , , and .

**Constraints**. 1 ≤ || ≤ 500 000. 1 ≤  ≤ 100 000. 0 ≤ ,  ≤ || −  (hence the indices  and  are 0-based).

**Output Format**. For each query, output “Yes” if +1. . .+−1 = +1. . .+−1 are equal, and “No”
otherwise.

**Sample 1.**
**Input:**
trololo

4

0 0 7

2 4 3

3 5 1

1 3 2

**Output**:

Yes

Yes

Yes

No

0 0 7 → trololo = trololo

2 4 3 → trololo = trololo

3 5 1 → trololo = trololo

1 3 2 → trololo ̸= trololo

I used the following algorithm

1. Fix 1 = 10^9 + 7 and 2 = 10^9 + 9.
2. Select a random  from 1 to 10^9. ( I choose x = 263 as large numbers cause overflow while powering up)
3. Compute arrays ℎ1[0..] and ℎ2[0..]: ℎ1[0] = ℎ2[0] = 0 and, for 1 ≤  ≤ , ℎ1[] = (0 · · · −1) mod
   1 and ℎ2[] = (0 · · · −1) mod 2. We illustrate this for ℎ1 below.

```
allocate ℎ1[0..]

ℎ1[0] ← 0

for  from 1 to :

    ℎ1[] ← ( · ℎ1[ − 1] + ) mod 1
```

4. For every query (, , ):

(a) Use precomputed hash values, to compute the hash values of the substrings +1 · · · +−1 and
+1 · · · +−1 modulo 1 and 2.

(b) Output “Yes”, if
( +1 · · · +−1) mod 1 = ( +1 · · · +−1) mod 1 and
( +1 · · · +−1) mod 2 = ( +1 · · · +−1) mod 2 .

(c) Otherwise, output “No”.

Finally for calculating the hash value I used this relation

( +1 · · · +−1) = ℎ[ + ] − ^l*ℎ[] .

I tried to code in c++ and it works for most of cases but fails only in one case which is

```
Failed case:

input string : abacabadabacaba
a ,b ,l: 0 8 7
My Output : No

But the output should be 'Yes' as we 'abacaba' for both a to l and b to l
```

I am not sure what the problem is, But when I code in python it works perfectly in this cases and results Yes for the above case. Can anyone help me understand the reasons.

My Code:

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Solver {
    string s;
public: 
    Solver(string s) : s(s) {   
        // initialization, precalculation
    }
    bool ask(int a, int b, int l) {
        return s.substr(a, l) == s.substr(b, l);
    }
    
    vector<long long int> HashTable(string s,long long int prime,long long int x){
        vector<long long int> H(s.length()+1,0);
        H[0] = 0;
        for(int i=1;i<s.length()+1;i++)
        {
            H[i] = ((H[i-1] * x + (int)(s[i-1])) % prime);
            }   
        return H;
    }
    vector<long long int> powernew(int length,long long int prime,long long int x)
    {
        vector<long long int> pow1(length+1,0);
        pow1[0] = 1;
        for(int i=1;i<length+1;i++)
        {
            pow1[i] = (long long int)(fmod(pow(x,i),prime)); 
        }
        return pow1;
    }
    
    long long int HashValue(vector<long long int> hash_table,long long int prime,long long int x,int start,int length,vector<long long int> y)
    {
            
        long long int hash_value = ((prime + (hash_table[start + length] - y[length] * hash_table[start]) % prime) % prime);
        return hash_value;
    }
    
    
    
    bool ask_fast(int a,int b,int l,string s,long long int m1,long long int m2,long long int x,vector<long long int> y1,
    vector<long long int> y2,vector<long long int> hash_table1,vector<long long int> hash_table2)
    {
            
        if(l==0)
            return (s[a] == s[b]);
        
        long long int a_hash1 = HashValue(hash_table1,m1,x,a,l,y1);
        long long int a_hash2 = HashValue(hash_table2,m2,x,a,l,y2);
        cout<<a_hash1<<" "<<a_hash2<<endl;
        cout<<s[a]<<s[a+l-1]<<endl;
        long long int b_hash1 = HashValue(hash_table1,m1,x,b,l,y1);
        long long int b_hash2 = HashValue(hash_table2,m2,x,b,l,y2);
        cout<<b_hash1<<" "<<b_hash2<<endl;
        cout<<s[b]<<s[b+l-1]<<endl;
        if((a_hash1 ==  b_hash1) && (a_hash2 == b_hash2))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

int main() {

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0), cin.tie(0);

    
    
    string s;
    int q;
    cin >> s >> q;
    Solver solver(s);
    
    //Added
    long long int m1 = 1000000000 + 7;
    long long int m2 = 1000000000 + 9;
    long long int x = 263;
    vector<long long int> y1 = solver.powernew(s.length(),m1,x);
    vector<long long int> y2 = solver.powernew(s.length(),m2,x);
    vector<int> hash_table1 = solver.HashTable(s,m1,x);
    vector<int> hash_table2 = solver.HashTable(s,m2,x);
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        int a, b, l;
        cin >> a >> b >> l;
        cout << (solver.ask_fast(a, b, l, s,m1,m2,x,y1,y2,hash_table1,hash_table2) ? "Yes\n" : "No\n");
    }

}
```

**Python**

```
# python3

import sys

class Solver:
    
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
        
    def ask(self, a, b, l):
        return s[a:a+l] == s[b:b+l]
    
    def HashTable(self,s,prime,x):
        H = list([] for _ in range(len(s)+1))
        H[0] = 0
        for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
            H[i] = (H[i-1] * x + ord(s[i-1])) % prime
            
        return H
    
    def powernew(self,length,prime,x):
        pow1 = list([] for _ in range(length+1))
        pow1[0] = 1
        for i in range(1,length+1):
            pow1[i] = pow(x,i,prime)
            
        return pow1
    
    def HashValue(self,hash_table,prime,x,start,length,y):
        hash_value = ((prime + (hash_table[start + length] - y[length] * hash_table[start]) % prime) % prime)
        return hash_value
    
    def ask_fast(self,a,b,l,s,m1,m2,x,y1,y2,hash_table1,hash_table2):
        a_hash1 = self.HashValue(hash_table1,m1,x,a,l,y1)
        a_hash2 = self.HashValue(hash_table2,m2,x,a,l,y2)
        
        b_hash1 = self.HashValue(hash_table1,m1,x,b,l,y1)
        b_hash2 = self.HashValue(hash_table2,m2,x,b,l,y2)
        
        if (a_hash1 == b_hash1) and (a_hash2 == b_hash2):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
        

s = sys.stdin.readline()
q = int(sys.stdin.readline())
#s = input()
#q = int(input())
solver = Solver(s)
#added
m1 = 1000000007
m2 = 1000000009
x = 263
y1 = solver.powernew(len(s),m1,x)
y2 = solver.powernew(len(s),m2,x)
hash_table1 = solver.HashTable(s,m1,x)
hash_table2 = solver.HashTable(s,m2,x)
#ends
for i in range(q):
    a, b, l = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split())
    #a, b, l = map(int, input().split())
    #print("Yes" if solver.ask(a, b, l) else "No")
    print("Yes" if solver.ask_fast(a, b, l, s, m1, m2, x, y1, y2, hash_table1, hash_table2) else "No")
```

Comment: Computing the hash seems very heavyweight compared to just comparing them?

Comment: Actually the test case have a time limit of one second. That's the problem where we can't use O(n^2) algorithms.

Comment: A comparison is O(n). Also it has a very low overhead compared to a hash. https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/5a8f945919d53da75c9a69f9facc1a5b